# Formula for the given sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> $$ 1,3,7,9,11,15,19,23,25,29,31,35,39,43,47,49,53,57,59,63,67,71,75,79,81\dots$$
>   Find the simplest formula for the given sequence.

Thanks to [Marcus Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/97648/marcus-andrews)' comment, I corrected the first term in the sequence and it looks like the sum of a number triangle:

\begin{align} &\color{red}2,4,\\ &\color{red}2,\color{red}2,4,4,4,\\ &\color{red}2,4,\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,\\ &\color{red}2,4,4,\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,4,\\ &\color{red}2,4,4,4,\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,4,4,\\ &\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4, \\ &\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,4,\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4, \end{align}

---

> But I'm not sure how to get a sequence formula from this, $a_n=$ ?

By the "simplest" It is meant, that it would be preferred expressing it using only standard arithmetic operations (and potentiation), over the use of elementary functions like sine or cosine or already existing function sequences, if possible.

Comment: I can only guess from the values given so far, but it almost looks like a triangle of sums. To extrapolate:

$$\begin{align}
&4,4,\\
&\color{red}2,\color{red}2,4,4,4,\\
&\color{red}2,4,\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,\\
&\color{red}2,4,4,\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,4,\\
&\color{red}2,4,4,4,\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,4,4,\\
&\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4, \\
&\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,4,\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
\end{align}$$

Does this fit your pattern?

Comment: @MarcusStuhr The first term works with either $-1,0$ or $1$ while the rest are unique; thus indeed it seems better to choose $2$ for the first term of the pattern sequence to get the triangle sums. (To have $\color{red}2,4$ in the first row of your pyramid; makes the first term in the initial sequence $1$ rather than $-1$) I'll **edit** the first term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference sequence  has twos at positions $3, 4, 8, 10, 15, 18, \ldots$. We see two subsequences $3,8,15,\ldots$ and $4,10,18,\ldots$ is this, i.e., we have twos whenever $n=m^2-1$ or $n=m(m+3)=(m+\frac32)^2-\frac94$. Thus

$$ a_n = 4n-2\lfloor\sqrt{n+1}-1\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\sqrt{n+\frac94}-\frac32\right\rfloor-1 $$

This seems to be what you want.

Comment: I wanted to avoid defined functions in my expression, but if the floor function is unavoidable, then I'll probably satisfy myself with your answer. (note that I edited the first term of the sequence)

Comment: I think you made a mistake somewhere, since your $a_n$ produces $1,\color{red}5,7,9,\color{red}{13},\color{red}{17},\color{red}{21}\dots$

Comment: Editing the $-1$ in the first floor gives $3,7,9,11,15\dots$ as it should. You missed that when taking the quadratic solution.

Answer (score 1):

Extrapolate the pattern:

$$\begin{align}
&4,4,\\
&\color{red}2,\color{red}2,4,4,4,\\
&\color{red}2,4,\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,\\
&\color{red}2,4,4,\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,4,\\
&\color{red}2,4,4,4,\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,4,4,\\
&\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4, \\
&\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,4,\color{red}2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
\end{align}$$

We'll define this triangle sequence $t_n$, and $1 + \sum t_n = a_n$, which we can frame as $4n - 2k$ for some $k$.

The triangle has two sequences running through it at positions $3, 8, 15, ...$ and $4, 10, 18, ...$, and these sequences are of form $k(k+1)$ and $k(k+3)$. Setting equal to $n$ and solving tells us how many of these terms exist, with minor adjustments for offsets / edge cases.

$$a_n = 4n - 2\lfloor\sqrt{n + 1}-1\rfloor  - 2\lfloor (\sqrt{4 n + 9} - 3)/2\rfloor - 1$$